# Decoding/Converting a hex string to specific format

Tags: c#, python-3.x, hex

I have been tasked with converting a hex string to a specific format but the developer of the software is not being of much assistance to the necessary steps to convert the string. I have managed to get the "before" and "after" formats of the string so I have something to work towards, but i am hoping that the community can help. I have been working in Python so i'm hoping that this solution can he done in that language.

The developer has provided little information on how to break it out other than this.

"here is the the c# code to break it out. It consists of a series of 2 byte integers...."

" Byte Description
' 0-799 Load data, 4 bytes each
' 800-1599 Position data, 4 bytes each"

```
public class PositionLoadPoint
{
   public float Position { get; private set; }
   public float Load { get; private set; }
    public PositionLoadPoint(float position, float load)
   {
       Position = position;
       Load = load;
   }
}
This method should return a list of points from an array of bytes:
public static IList<PositionLoadPoint> GetPositionLoadPoints(byte[] bytes)
{
   IList<PositionLoadPoint> result = new List<PositionLoadPoint>();
   int midIndex = bytes.Length / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < midIndex; i += 4)
   {
       byte[] load = new byte[4];
       byte[] position = new byte[4];
        Array.Copy(bytes, i, load, 0, 4);
       Array.Copy(bytes, midIndex + i, position, 0, 4);
        var point = new PositionLoadPoint(BitConverter.ToSingle(load, 0),
                                          BitConverter.ToSingle(position, 0));
        result.Add(point);
   }
    return result;
}
```

From what I have gathered this c# program likely does parse out and convert the 2 byte integer data. It appears that the 2 byte integer data is formatted where the front portion (loads) are coming from the front of the array, all the rear portion (postions) are coming after "midIndex".

This is the original hex string

```
00706A450090574500F0484500C0394500802D45001027450050284500E0304500603E4500204D450010594500C05E4500505C4500F051450060414500C02D4500E01A4500C00C4500C0064500000B4500D019450060314500E04D4500006A450008804500A08545007884450030794500205F4500E03F4500D0214500F00A450080FF440070024500D0124500202E450060504500F0744500D08B4500009B4500A0A7450040B24500F8BB4500F0C54500D0D0450080DC450028E8450068F2450000FA450028FE4500D8FE4500F0FC4500B8F9450088F6450068F44500D8F34500C8F44500B8F6450028F94500A0FB4500F0FD45000C0046002401460058024600B803460038054600B8064600F4074600980846005C08460010074600B40446009001460050FC450040F6450048F2450068F1450020F4450040FA45006C01460044064600BC0A4600F80D4600280F4600CC0D4600B409460010034600C0F44500D0E04500F8CB4500C8B7450090A5450038964500308A45009881450060784500B072450010704500206E4500706A45000000005C8F0240D7A380408FC2CD409A9911413D0A3F4152B86E4152B89041F628AC41713DCA41A470EB413D0A08427B141C42CDCC314285EB4842C3F56042B81E79420A578842856B93423D8A9D4214AEA6420000AF42ECD1B6425C8FBE423D8AC6425C0FCF425238D8420000E2423333EC42E17AF64252380043ECD104439AD9084333330C43D7E30E43CD0C114348E11243299C1443146E1643D7631843146E1A43856B1C43A4301E43B89E1F43F6A82043B85E214329DC21431F45224385AB22430A1723435278234314AE23439A9923437B1423437B1422435C8F20437B941E4333331C438F821943CD8C16430A5713439AD90F433D0A0C4366E60743A4700343C375FD4214AEF34252B8E94252B8DF4271BDD542CDCCCB4285EBC1427B14B8428F42AE42A470A44200809A42CD4C9042F6A88542B81E75427B145E420AD74642F628304285EB1A4252B807429A99ED410000D0418FC2B5410AD79D410AD787413D0A6741713D4241A4702141EC5104413333D3400000A040CDCC5C4000000040295C4F3F0AD7A33D00000000
```

This is the final format that the hex needs converted too.

```
0.11 , 14083 
0.23 , 14033
0.46 , 14013
0.69 , 13905
0.92 , 13767
1.55 , 13744
2.22 , 13585
2.89 , 13675
3.56 , 13677
4.54 , 13539
5.61 , 13357
6.67 , 13287
7.74 , 13668
9.03 , 14350
10.45 , 15073
11.86 , 15544
13.27 , 15654
14.82 , 15944
16.53 , 16215
18.24 , 16453
19.94 , 16725
21.72 , 16908
23.67 , 17149
25.62 , 17466
27.57 , 17828
29.54 , 18133
31.69 , 18312
33.83 , 18585
35.97 , 19025
38.09 , 19668
40.38 , 20443
42.66 , 20364
44.94 , 20018
47.2 , 19619
49.54 , 19211
51.96 , 18805
54.38 , 18448
56.81 , 18173
59.23 , 18015
61.79 , 17828
64.32 , 17677
66.87 , 17542
69.42 , 17434
72.03 , 17454
74.64 , 17399
77.26 , 17269
79.87 , 17038
82.52 , 16739
85.17 , 16888
87.82 , 17075
90.48 , 17272
93.12 , 17502
95.75 , 17799
98.37 , 17993
100.99 , 18033
103.59 , 18058
106.15 , 18090
108.7 , 18078
111.27 , 18101
113.81 , 18048
116.26 , 17970
118.72 , 17905
121.19 , 17877
123.66 , 17920
125.96 , 17903
128.28 , 17775
130.6 , 17558
132.92 , 17398
135.07 , 17159
137.2 , 16945
139.34 , 16794
141.48 , 16707
143.41 , 16641
145.3 , 16543
147.19 , 16539
149.09 , 16520
150.75 , 16440
152.37 , 16306
153.98 , 16215
155.59 , 16181
156.95 , 16071
158.23 , 15892
159.5 , 15711
160.8 , 15621
161.82 , 15576
162.75 , 15569
163.69 , 15520
164.63 , 15415
165.3 , 15279
165.89 , 15162
166.48 , 15122
167.07 , 14976
167.39 , 14915
167.65 , 15001
167.9 , 15173
168.15 , 15251
168.15 , 15349
168.09 , 15502
168.03 , 15784
167.97 , 15959
167.68 , 15832
167.34 , 15507
167 , 15381
166.66 , 15151
166.11 , 14970
165.51 , 14816
164.92 , 14636
164.33 , 14475
163.55 , 14238
162.73 , 13731
161.91 , 13326
161.1 , 13048
160.12 , 12775
159.1 , 12715
158.08 , 12748
157.07 , 12773
155.91 , 12764
154.71 , 12703
153.5 , 12570
152.3 , 12555
150.99 , 12406
149.62 , 12135
148.25 , 11804
146.89 , 11512
145.42 , 11047
143.89 , 10545
142.38 , 9960
140.86 , 9393
139.28 , 9066
137.61 , 8782
135.94 , 8582
134.28 , 8473
132.61 , 8429
130.78 , 8317
128.98 , 8143
127.18 , 8133
125.38 , 8347
123.44 , 8811
121.49 , 9368
119.53 , 9770
117.57 , 10086
115.52 , 10395
113.41 , 10840
111.29 , 11309
109.16 , 11632
106.99 , 11774
104.71 , 11814
102.42 , 11686
100.14 , 11488
97.85 , 11265
95.43 , 11063
93.01 , 10980
90.6 , 10640
88.19 , 10245
85.7 , 9841
83.19 , 9367
80.69 , 9014
78.19 , 8772
75.66 , 8608
73.11 , 8477
70.55 , 8295
67.99 , 8260
65.43 , 8337
62.84 , 8508
60.26 , 8815
57.68 , 9184
55.07 , 9562
52.5 , 9889
49.92 , 10058
47.33 , 10357
44.72 , 10660
42.18 , 10967
39.68 , 11273
37.16 , 11525
34.64 , 11619
32.22 , 11675
29.9 , 11720
27.58 , 11749
25.25 , 11714
23.04 , 11613
21.01 , 11502
18.98 , 11349
16.95 , 11172
15.04 , 11061
13.4 , 11069
11.75 , 11137
10.1 , 11163
8.47 , 11180
7.37 , 11287
6.17 , 11385
4.96 , 11603
3.83 , 11862
3.1 , 12134
2.38 , 12405
1.65 , 12643
0.92 , 12875
0.72 , 13118
0.48 , 13388
0.24 , 13680
0.11 , 14083
```

Comment: What is that output format? It is not a data structure? Just an output that is printed?

Comment: It is the expect output of that hex string. I have added some additional details in the original question

Comment: and yes this is just an output that is printed.

Comment: You speak of *the "leading" and "following" data*... can you clearly mark out what that is? Is it included in the hex input?

Comment: Good question. I have updated the expected output data with lines indicating the "leading" and "following" data. and yes you are correct. From what i have been told, the "leading" and "following" data is within the hex input string as well.

Comment: I have played a bit with the data, but don't see a pattern that matches with the output. So I will leave you to it. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I just learnt something new from the developer and modified my original question. I apologize for that since your efforts seem to be in vein. It appears the "leading" and "following" data were not in the original hex string at all. So all it needs converted to is the (load, position) printed output format. The developer also added a description of the data format within the hex string "Byte Description ' 0-799 Load data, 4 bytes each ' 800-1599 Position data, 4 bytes each". Seeing how your are familiar with this could you take a second look??

Comment: I posted a non-memory-efficient version for you to test. It contains the basic elements for you to parse the data. However, the output data you posted doesn't seem to match the spec. Have you confirmed that is the correct output data for that input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the spec, this is a quick method that should match the C# code above. This doesn't match your output though, so I'm wondering if your output example data matches your input data.

```py
import struct

def convert(hex_string):
    raw_data = bytearray.fromhex(hex_string)
    # The load and position data are split in the middle
    mid_index = int(len(raw_data) / 2)

    # The number of points should be equal to half of
    # the number of 4-byte values in the byte array.
    # Process the first half of the array as `load`,
    # and the second half as `position`.
    format_str = 'f' * int(len(raw_data) / 2 / 4)
    load_data = struct.unpack(format_str, raw_data[:mid_index])
    position_data = struct.unpack(format_str, raw_data[mid_index:])

    # Combine the load and position data into tuples.
    return list(zip(load_data, position_data))
```

Comment: its been a long day already, but your method is broke. looks like b isn't defined anywhere. Is b = hex string or raw_Data??

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste error. Edited.